# Longest line inside polygon must pass through two vertices

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, polygons

Given a non-convex polygon and I need to find the longest line inside it. Intuitively I fill it must pass *at least* through two vertices of the polygon, but I can't prove it. How to prove it?

Comment: I think this is true for a convex polygon but may not be true if it is not convex.

Comment: The maximum of a convex function (like the distance from a point) on a bounded convex set (like a convex polygon) is always achieved on the boundary.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the longest line does not necessarily start and end at vertices: it may touch two or more vertices in the middle.  This must still be counted as "inside" the polygon.

[image]

Comment: And actually even if the line has to be in the polygon's interior, the longest still does may not end on vertices. An hourglass shape would be enough to show this.

Comment: It does "pass through" at least two vertices though.

Comment: But it still passes through two vertices. I didn't say that it must start and end on the vertex

Answer (score 1):

If the line does not end on the boundary, we can extend it. Hence we need only consider lines starting and ending on the boundary.

If no vertex is on the line, we can rotate it around its midpoint slightly without touching a vertex.
Similarly, if exactly one vertex is on the line, we can rotate the line around that vertex slightly without touching another vertex.
In at least one direction, the rotation will make the line longer, contradicting its maximality.

Remains to show that there exists a maximal line to begin with. The choice of the four coordinates of the two endpoints is from a closed and bounded subset of $\Bbb R^4$. The condition that the line is inside the polygon (including its boudary) is a closed condition: If some point of the line is exterior, then small changes to the endpoints cannot mend that. Thus even with this condition added, we consider the distance function on a compact set. Every continuous function on a compact has a maximum.

Comment: "In at least one direction, the rotation will make the line longer, contradicting its maximality." What if d(length)/d(angle) = 0? Can we guarantee that it must be a local minimum and not a local maximum? I guess we need to use the convexity of the length as a function of the endpoints.